# ProGuard Obfuscation

Tags: java, jar, obfuscation, proguard, executable-jar

I am able to obfuscate my Application with ProGuard using Ant Scripts. I followed the steps as listed on: [Obfuscating a NetBeans Java Application Project](http://netbeans.dzone.com/tips/obfuscating-netbeans-java-appl)

But when I try to run the jar by double click or using `java -jar myjarname.jar`, it gives VM Error. However it executes by using `java -cp myjarname.jar com.mypackage.myclass`

Can u help me how to specify the manifest? Or let me know how to fix this issue?

Comment: what is that VM Error message? i don't think it has got anything to do with Obfuscation. You should probably tell Ant to include the MANIFEST.MF file containing the Main-Class entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried putting a file `MANIFEST.MF` into the root of your JAR with something like the following contents:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: com.mypackage.myclass
```

FYI, Main-Class denotes the class that should be runned when the jar file is executed.